# Clustering, reducing number of levels of categorical variable

Tags: statistical-significance, clustering, categorical-data, aggregation, many-categories

I'm dealing with this big dataset which has:

- 1 categorical variable with 90 levels that represent some sort
  of "geographical area"
- 3 continuous variables

What I'm trying to do is to "aggregate" the levels of the categorical variable, to a maximum of 10.

I don't know exactly which technique I should use to accomplish this, for example whether I should use factor analysis or some clustering (unsupervised)

Comment: How about creating groups based on geographical regions, such as Northeast, Southwest, etc., that are more meaningful from the business perspective?

Comment: Yes, but I also want to see if there is some analogy between areas in different regions, in order to investigate why!

Comment: What do you mean by "clustering (unsupervised)"?

Comment: Have a look at:   https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/227125/preprocess-categorical-variables-with-many-values/277302#277302